# Acceleration in a space capsule which is falling to the earth

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, acceleration

At first I apologize for asking such a career killing question in such an elite platform. Today I tried to prove something to four graduated engineers which I will mention below. The argument continued for an hour and finally I cannot convince them. So, your testimony will be very helpfull for me.

Assuming that there is a space capsule located far above from earth surface with zero volecity relative to the earth at t=T0. There is a poor guy standing upright in the cabin and an accelerometer placed on the table. Accleerometer's z-axis is pointing same direction with earth-gravity vector.

And then the space capsule starts to fall freely to the earth without air resistence. There is no atmosphere and no frictional forces. The capsule will not rotate and Accelerometer's z-axis will be kept in same direction with earth-gravity vector along the voyage.

Question-1: Accelerometer measures what on z-axis?

Question-2: Does the guy standing upright at t=T0, feels any gravitational force? Or does he feel weightlessness?

Thanks your interests from now

Comment: I don't quite understand the closing of this, but ... Q1: zero  Q2: weightlessness

Comment: I also think the closure was a little on the harsh side, though I see it does look like a homework question. Anyhow, you have only to look at videos from the International Space Station to see what happens, because that is falling freely in Earth's gravitational field. Accelerometers on the ISS would read zero and the atsronauts are weightless. Exactly the same applies to your capsule.

Comment: I had apologized readers at first for asking such a silly question. I am sure an average techical guy can answer these questions. Believe or not today I debate an hour to convince four graduated engineer that what "garyp" said is true. Thanks for your interests.

Comment: Point your friends to the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page on accelerometers.  In particular, "accelerometers in free fall orbiting and accelerating due to the gravity of Earth will measure zero."  See the second Wikipedia link for further explanation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer#Physical_principles

Comment: There is one important semantic note concerning the word "weight". In some contexts (usually early in instruction) the word is assigned to the the force of gravity on an object, and in latter contexts it is assigned to the contact forces needed to keep the object in place. The word "weightlessness" is relying on the latter meaning, and accelerometers basically measure the latter meaning for a test mass.